# Android getTargetFragment().getView() returning null

Tags: android

I have an issue with orientation changes and a retained Fragment.

In the retained Fragment in `onActivityCreated()` I use `getTargetFragment().getView().find...`

Sometimes the method returns null. I do not know why. I use the compatibility library v.4.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but I stumbled upon this and happen to have a work around. In my experience when working within fragments and switching between them the onCreate methods fire a little too quickly so sometimes the layout in not fully initialized. The work around I've used fire off a timer task to make the call a little after the onCreate is called. The delay seems to always give it enough time. I have my own timer singleton and you would need to construct your own timer to schedule tasks upon but you get the idea. Hope this helps.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final QueueFragmentTab thisFrag = this;

    TimerHelper.getInstance().scheduleTask(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             //getview goes here
            Log.w(tag, "" + thisFrag.getView());

        }
    }, 100);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_queue, container, false);

}
```

Comment: I'm even later but I think your problem is you're trying to get the view before inflating the layout.